# Why is adding 'form-control' bootstrap class in Django form not working?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, bootstrap-5

I am creating a login page without an inbuilt model form. I am using FormAPI of Django and followed all the steps to add a class attribute to the input fields of my form. But it still looks like a basic form without bootstrap.

forms.py:

```
#Login Form

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

Base template file to be inherited:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'account/images/logo.ico' type='image/x-icon' %}">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'account/css/style.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
  </head>
  <body class="forbody">
    <div class="container trp" style="margin-top: 2%; display: inline-block;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{% static 'account/images/Logo.png' %}" alt="Logo" style="height: 60%; width: auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="width: 40%; margin-top: 10%;">
        <div class="container" style="width: auto; margin-top: 8%;">
            <div class="container" style="background-color: #696969; height: auto; width: auto; margin-top: 8%;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px;">
                        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% block formcontent %} {% endblock formcontent %}
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        {% block loginbtn %} {% endblock loginbtn %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 12px;">
                        {% block outerlink %} {% endblock outerlink %}
                        {% block messages %} {% endblock messages %}
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actual login template:

```
{% extends 'account/forms_base.html' %}
{% block title %}Log-in{% endblock title %}
{% block formcontent %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{error}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% for fm in form %}
        {{fm.label_tag}} {{fm}} {{fm.error|striptags}} <br><br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock formcontent %}
{% block loginbtn %}
    <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Login">
{% endblock loginbtn %}
{% block outerlink %}
    <small style="margin-top: 5px;">To register <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="signuptag">Click Here</a></small>
{% endblock outerlink %}
{% block messages %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <span {% if message.tags %} class="{{message.tags}}" {% endif %}>{{message}}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock messages %}
```

Where am I going wrong here? When I view the source page on the browser, the class attribute does not show at all!

Comment: How about your views.py: are you instantiating LoginForm() ok? Any chance it's getting changed at all before getting passed in the context?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there! The problem was indeed lying there.